# Ubuntu MATE 16.04 - Bad microphone sound quality

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, ubuntu-mate

I'm currently using Ubuntu MATE 16.04(as the title implies) on a desktop PC with external microphone.
Whenever I try to talk with somebody via Skype, the participant/s in the conversation hear very annoying static and buzzing sound. If I decrease the volume, the static decreases respectively but then nobody can hear my voice. The same applies when I try to make a sound record or a screencast.
I've also tried it under Win 10 and it was a bit better but only a bit.

I have ASRock Z170 Extreme 4 motherboard and I use the internal sound card.

Here is some settings info:

alsamixer's capture levels:

```
<Front Mic Boost> 0<>0
Line Boost 0<>0
Capture 100<>100
Capture 1 0<>0
Input Source Rear Mic
Input Source 1 Front Mic
Rear Mic Boost 22<>22
```

PulseAudio Volume Control

Input Devices tab -> Built-in Audio Analog Stereo -> Port: Rear Microphone(plugged in) (at 46%)
Configuration tab -> Built-in Audio Profile: Analog Stereo Duplex

I've searched for another thread with similar problem and eventually a solution but I couldn't find anything useful.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: I would try a different microphone to see if the issue persists first.